# How can you do alternative row color but just on visible rows?

Tags: jquery, css-tables

I have the following code to do alternative row colors which works fine:

```
$("table.altRow tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DEDFDE");
$("table.altRow tr:even").css("background-color", "#EEECEE");
```

but I have certain cases where some rows are hidden so I wanted to see if there was any way to do alternative row colors but just apply to visible rows?

Comment: How are you hiding them?

Comment: Try maybe `:visible`?

Comment: @Paulie_D - I am hiding rows by class name (certain tr have class name = "specialRow" and i have doing #(".specialRow.hide())

Comment: Then, in CSS, I think you would have to use the [not] operator to remove that 'specialRow' class from your selection. I'm sure there is an equivalent in JQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/**
 *  Iterate each visible row, if :odd or :even, apply 
 *  the relevant background colour depending on a flag.
**/
var evenOdd = 0;
$("table.altRow tr:visible").each(function() {  
    $(this).css("background-color", ( evenOdd ? "#DEDFDE" : "#EEECEE" ));
    evenOdd = !evenOdd;
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/uMP5x/7/

As **Andreas** mentioned, you can use jQuery's `.each()`'s first arugment to your advantage with modulus, removing my initial need for a Boolean.

```
/**
 *  Iterate each visible row, if :odd or :even, apply 
 *  the relevant background colour depending if it's a 0 or 1
 *  after a simple MOD division.
**/
$("table.altRow tr:visible").each(function( index ) {  
    $(this).css("background-color", ( index % 2 ? "#DEDFDE" : "#EEECEE" ));
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uMP5x/8/

Comment: Hmm, have you verified this works? My question is, do `:odd` and `:even` CSS selectors include hidden rows?

Comment: Apologies, unverified to be quite honest, just Fiddling now ;) But I see what you mean by not-counting a hidden row, but technically speaking, it shouldn't matter if it's only collecting visible in the first place.

Comment: [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/): _Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and **return true** if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments._

Comment: Right, it should only be _applying_ the CSS classes to visible rows, but the calculation of whether a row is even or odd might take into account hidden rows.

Comment: How about using the {not) operator to remove the 'specialRow' elements from the overall selection?

Comment: Edited after realising my original Snippet far from worked ;) and thank you +1 Andreas for noting it was just a boolean method!

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't see that comment! Wasn't in the original question, I'll edit one in for that =)

Comment: Why not using the first parameter of the `.each()` callback instead of a global variable? `.each(function(idx) { $(this).css("background-color", ( (idx % 2) ? "#DEDFDE" : "#EEECEE" )); })`

Comment: @Andreas That's a smart idea, why didn't I? simply because I hadn't of thought of it =) but you should post that, I couldn't take credit of that! Edit if you wish =)

Answer (score 0):

I searched all over stackoverflow for an answer and I didn't get any. Then finally my manager helped me out with this. So for whichever row (`<tr>` element) that you want to style, create a `ui:field` entry in the ui.xml binder file.

```
<tr ui:field="stylingRow">
```

then in the corresponding Java class use the @UiField annotation to get this particular row's DOM element.

```
@UiField TableRowElement stylingRow;
```

Then you can do anything with that.. Add styles and the like...

```
stylingRow.getStyle().setBackgroundColor("black");
```

There are a plethora of methods available in the `TableRowElement`, So if only a couple of rows are hidden or something and you need the zebra styling for all the visible ones.. you can manually change the style of the hidden ones using the above statements.

Answer (score -2):

CSS3 gives you neat way of doing this:

```
 tr:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color:  #000;  
 }
 tr:nth-child(even) { 
      background-color:  #FFF;
 }
```

This will set color only on the visible rows.

Comment: `nth-child` uses DOM structure and ignores hidden rows

Comment: I agree with @Andreas, this wont work with hidden rows.

Comment: This will apply styling to all, not just visible.